# Adding pagination to HTML table using NgxPaginationModule results in error

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-pagination

I am trying to add pagination to my HTML table in angular 11 using `NgxPaginationModule`. The backend service is in asp.net and the data is getting properly displayed without pagination.
Here is my corresponding html and transcript file.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
        <th>Modified By</th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor = "let dataItem of CardList | paginate: config ">
        <td>{{dataItem.id}}</td>
        <td>{{dataItem.createdBy}}</td>
        <td>{{dataItem.modifiedBy}}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1"
          data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
(click)="editClick(dataItem)"
data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard = "false"
          >
          <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pencil-square" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456l-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
          </svg>
          </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1"
                (click)="deleteClick(dataItem)"
                >
                  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-trash-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v7a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0v-7z"/>
                  </svg>
                  </button>
        </td>
    
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-del-card',
  templateUrl: './del-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./del-card.component.css']
})
export class DelCardComponent implements OnInit {
  config: any;
  

  constructor(private service:SharedService) { 
    this.config = {
      itemsPerPage: 5,
      currentPage: 1,
      totalItems: 4
    };
    console.log(this.config)
  }
  pageChanged(event){
    this.config.currentPage = event;
  }

  CardList:any=[];
  crd:any;
  ModalTitle:string;
  ActivateAddCardComponent:boolean=false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshCardList();
    
  }

  addClick(){
    this.crd={
      id:0,
      createdBy:"",
      modifiedBy:""
    
    }
    this.ModalTitle="Add Card";
    this.ActivateAddCardComponent=true;

  }
  closeClick(){
    this.ActivateAddCardComponent=false;
    this.refreshCardList();
  }
  editClick(item){
    console.log(item);
    this.crd=item;
    this.ModalTitle="Edit Employee";
    this.ActivateAddCardComponent=true;
  }


  refreshCardList(){
    this.service.getCardList().subscribe(data =>{
      this.CardList=data;
      //this.totalLength=data.length;
      
    });
  }

  deleteClick(item){
    if(confirm('Are you sure??')){
      this.service.deleteCard(item.id).subscribe(data=>{
        alert(data.toString());
        this.refreshCardList();
      })
    }
  }

}
```

I am getting below error "Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context" after I added the pagination to my html table:
[image: Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context]

Please help in rectifying the problem as I am new to angular.

Comment: Seems you didn't import the module

Comment: i did imported the module in my app.module.ts

Comment: Try not using the this.config in paginate object, instead use the property of this.config, ie:  paginate { itemsPerPage: config.itemsPerPage }

Comment: still getting the same error